# Ubuntu Printing?

Tags: duplex-printing

We setup a Ubuntu server for our print server. We have a combination of Konica and HP model printers. For the HP models that are capable of it doublesided priting works fine. I cannot get it to work on Any Konica. The option in the properties only shows 1 sided. In the CUPS URL it shows 2 sided but when you set that as default it still reverts back to 1 sided. Is there any way to do double sided printing with a Konica on Ubuntu?

Comment: See an apparently similar bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/foomatic-db/+bug/432235. Contact Konica support for this issue with their product.

Comment: shutdown cups and look inside `printers.conf`. Change the setting responsible and see if that works. (cups needs to be stopped otherwise cups overwrites the config).